# EF Code First Fluent API set Read-Only?

Tags: entity-framework, fluent

Is there any way to make a field ReadOnly with Fluent API? I am currently using DataAnnotations,

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
```

but I would like to do it with Fluent API. Any help, please!

Comment: No. Use a private setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the `DbModelBuilder`'s fluent interface then *no*, you *cant*.

The `ReadOnlyAttribute` is not part of DataAnnotations (`system.componentmodel.dataannotations`), and it is part of the reason you cant do it. DbModelBuilder fluid interface will apply for the Entity related attributes, in which ReadOnly is not part of.

The other part of it is that "read only" is not a common property of columns in databases. How should the c# attribute "read only" translate to a column, if there is no equivalent? (One way is usually implement triggers for that btw, but its not the case. Locks are also a similiar feature but are not the same thing, since the value could be changed).

If you are worried about having both DataAnnotations and Fluent API in this case, dont worry, since (at least the way I think) ReadyOnly *shouldnt* be avaible in Entity configurations. It is not part of common database logic.

I would say just keep the DataAnnotation.

**Remmember**: If you really need to prevent changes in that field, do it with native SQL (trigger etc), since developers often have to use native SQL here and there.